# How to send an array with objects to next screen in react-native?

Tags: javascript, android, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I want to sent atn array to next screen, this atn array is fine and all the item are easily accesible...I am new to react-native, okay this atn array is on ListM.js and I want to take this array to VenueD.js.... help thanks in advance.

Comment: it depends on which router you are using  basically you can send by using params

Comment: I am using React-navigation, and my array which name is atn[{ },{}'{},]contains objects and resides at ListM.js, I  want to send it to VenuD.js How please help

Comment: Do not add question details as comments.  Please perform an edit on your question and transfer the commented information, then delete your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass data from a component to another by using `props`

It would be something like this:

```
//MyComponent.js
const myArr = [1, 2, 3];

<MyChild array={myArr} />

//MyChild.js - if statless component
const MyChild = (props) => {
  const receivedArray = props.myArr;
  // or const { myArr } = props;
}

//MyChild.js - if class component
class MyChild extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
  }
  render() {
    const receivedArray = this.props.myArr;
    return(

    );
  }
}
```

Note that there might be typos, I wrote the code here in the comment.

I suggest you to check out the official docs for further information.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/props.html

https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/components-props-and-state.html

Hope it helps

Edit:

According to the provided info in the comments below, make sure you have set up your navigation components in your root file. 
If you are being able to navigate and just need to send params from a component to another, then you may call your navigate method like this `navigate('RouteToVenuD', {atn})`. 
Then `atn` will be availble on `VenuD` as `this.props.navigation.state.params.atn`.

Hope it helps

Comment: I am using React-navigation, and my array which name is atn[{ },{}'{},]contains objects and resides at ListM.js, I want to send it to VenuD.js How please help, thank you for answering.

Comment: I added more info in the answer, take a look if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

As you're using *react-navigation*, you can bypass your data to next screen with:

### from_screen.js

```js
navigateTo() {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('ToScreen', {
        data: this.YOUR_ARRAY,
    });
}
```

### to_screen.js

then you can get back your data right in next screen.

```js
const { state, setParams, navigate } = this.props.navigation;
const params = state.params || {};

console.log(params.data);
```